# In Corda, TransactionResolutionException when verifying a transaction

Tags: corda

In a Corda flow, I am receiving and verifying a transaction as follows:

```
@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Responder(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val stx = counterpartySession.receive<SignedTransaction>().unwrap { it }
        stx.verify(serviceHub, false)
    }
}
```

However, this is throwing the following exception:

> net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionResolutionException: Transaction
>   resolution failure for
>   3D90346DD7F7397479312EF4DD5A4741F4CA31C2070BC4F8A0588974B1CD1523

What is the cause of this `TransactionResolutionException`, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

When a node verifies a transaction, it doesn't just verify the transaction itself. It also verifies the entire transaction chain. A `TransactionResolutionException` indicates that one or more of the transactions in the transaction chain is missing and cannot be verified.

To avoid this, you should send transactions using `SendTransactionFlow`, and receive transactions using `ReceiveTransactionFlow`. This flow pair does two things:

- It sends the transaction in question
- It allows the receiving node to download from the counterparty all the transactions they are missing in the chain of the transaction they are receiving

Answer (score 0):

In the node you are verifying you don't have the `TransactionState` that the passed input references too.

It is not correct to pass transaction for signing using `Send` or `SendAndReceive`.
It is better to use flows `SendTransactionFlow` and `ReceiveTransactionFlow` which will download the states those inputs reference.

If you can't send a `SignedTransaction` as above flows require (because for example you are sending a `FilteredTransaction`), you can send it with `FlowSession.send()` method, but the owner of the input responds with `SendStateAndRefFlow` flow, and the requester can receive it `ReceiveStateAndRefFlow` to add the inputs on the original transaction.

This will allow to have the referenced states of the inputs in all nodes, allowing you to verify the transaction.